# UART communication not working without injecting voltage in pin headers

Tags: pcb-design, noise, uart

[image]

I have a bluetooth module (rn4020) talking via UART to a stm32f103c8t6 MCU in a custom PCB, I also have an OLED screen and  some pin headers for listening what either module receives (as seen in the right top of the schematic).

The thing is that without connecting a FTDI chip in the pin headers, communication between stm32 and RN4020 does not work, I know this because the OLED screen outputs a message whenever a message from the bluetooth is received by the microcontroller (which is the first event to happen) and the message is not being shown in the OLED screen. I am not connecting ground from the FTDI chip in the pin headers and the communication proceeds normally which leds me to believe 3.8 volts injection is the thing making UART communication work (in contrast with 3.3 volts communication  without connecting anything in pin headers).

I've also seen that boards that pretend to achieve a similar functionality like Arduino Uno have some resistors for switching the UC communicates, though I know this is not the case I am looking for and makes me believe the problem I have can be noise related

Comment: I'm surprised that this works with the FTDI chip connected, because that would be shorting 2 TX's together. First of all I would always connect the FTDI gnd to your circuit, otherwise you can expect weird effects due to the protection diodes. Second, try connecting only the FTDI RX to either line and see what you get. A logic analyzer or scope connected to those lines might also help.

Comment: UART is still not working If only FTDI's RX is connected, both pins are require (TX and RX), I will work with scope soon. What would be a better way of achieving what I want without shorting to TX's?

Comment: You forgot to connect boot0.  Also your stacking of power pins on top of each other in the schematic is dubious - are you sure they really both get connected?

Comment: No, Boot0 is connected, the screenshot is not complete, every power pin is connected I am sure since I did the pcb and checked specifically for that

Comment: If you want help, you need to post the *actual* schematic, not something that is "incomplete" and shows errors you are only going to claim have been corrected.

Comment: Are Vbat and nRST also disconnected or connected somewhere? Maybe configuration error on firmware, like UART TX pins accidentally open-drain? As this is a 3.3V system, do not give it 5V signals from FTDI to rise the pin voltage to 3.8, this means current is injected to the system via internal protection diodes of those pins.

Comment: I've solved it through injecting 3.3v through those pins, I've checked configuration and TX both are push-pull

Comment: @PaulMaxAvalosAguilar - Welcome to the site. You said that you: "*solved it through injecting 3.3v through those pins*". Which pins? Do you mean Vbat and nRST, mentioned in an earlier comment? (Note that you must not connect nRST *directly* to 3.3V.) On Stack Exchange sites, this question is not closed by your comment. It is only marked as closed if someone writes an *answer* explaining the solution, in the box below titled "Your Answer" and you then "accept" that answer (green tick). Can you do that (write a full explanation in the box "Your Answer" and accept it) please? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I'll write an answer, I meant tx and rx pins